# why i have rusty components around/behind my brand new 4x4 renault duster's back wheels

Tags: renault, 4wd, duster

I bought a brand new Renault duster 2021 4x4, and today after 10 days of buying my new car, I noticed a rusty components around my back wheels, as follow:-

[image: Rear wheel from below]

so is this normal?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! As with most vehicles, when you run it down the road, it's going to get dirty. If you think this is out of the ordinary, get it cleaned up, then run it for another 10 days and see if you see it again. Really, it just looks like road grime to me.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 i am talking about the component marked in red and not the whole area. i think this is called the `knuckle and the driveshaft` they are fully rusted as shown in the picture

Comment: Bare iron is going to rust. This is only surface rust. Really, nothing to worry about IMHO.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 why this is bare iron and not been painted... is this normal to have the knuckle and the driveshaft as bare iron that is not protected/painted ?

Comment: Any component on a “new” car can be months or even a couple of years old.

Comment: In your question, you said dusty,  did you mean rusty?

Comment: I have seen cast components from cars that are 40 or 50 years old... and they are still fine while the car itself is long gone.

Comment: If you do a search for photos of other ‘duster’ cars rear suspension, you will see they look the same.

Comment: @HandyHowie yes sorry i correct it

Comment: @HandyHowie so doe snot mean it is normal to have rusty components in a new car as shown in my picture?

Comment: @testtest where you are? This car is called Dacia Duster here and in most other markets.

Comment: @fraxinus i am in the middle east and the car is called Renault Duster

Comment: Middle East? You don't have regular snowfalls in winter with salt on the road spread by road maintenance, do you? Dusters are rather good in regard to the rust even in Europe.

Comment: @fraxinus no snow or salt in the roads, you are correct

Comment: Must admit, I wouldn’t be happy to see that on my new car, even if the component will last the life of the vehicle.

Comment: @HandyHowie yes me too, i contact our Renault dealer and i am waiting for their feedback

Answer (score 2):

Rust on these parts is rarely a concern. They are not a sheet metal to be perforated by the rust and the rust cannot make them weak enough to fail before the warranty expires (and in the general case, they are one of the last to need replacement).

That's why they leave them unpainted.

p.s. painting them is not really going to help. These are made of cast iron and are not trivial to paint, the usual result when some entusiast goes on and paints them is the paint forming tiny pockets where water and salt accumulate and accelerate the corrosion. And after a while, the paint flakes off anyway.

Comment: so this components is normal to be rusty? and does this happen on most car manufacturers ?

Comment: Looking at my cars (all 20+ years): two of them rusty in the same places, one of them not much rusty because of minor oil leaks. The only reason you can see such a bright orange rust is the complete absence of leaked oil or grease. The oil leak absence is good by itself.

Comment: your car is 20++ years mine is brand new, so that why i am asking if it is normal to have these components rusty in the way i showed in the picture

Comment: I am used to seeing rusty cast iron parts in new cars as well. It is normal. Nothing bad will happen with these parts in the near 20 years, that's what I meant. Even if they break, it will not be because of the rust. In a few weeks or months of daily use, with the help of some tiny (also pretty normal) oil leak and the dirt, the rust will lose its bright appearance and will look just like under any other car.

Comment: p.s. I am yet to see a driveshaft broken in the middle. They always break near the ends, where they are extensively greased, sealed from atmospheric factors and the rust has no chance.

Comment: can you advice on what you meant by `I am yet to see a driveshaft broken in the middle. They always break near the ends, where they are extensively greased, sealed from atmospheric factors and the rust has no chance`

Comment: Driveshafts do break sometimes, but it is not because of the rust. They break at their ends, exactly where there cannot be any rust. It is not to say Duster driveshafts are prone to breaking, as far as I am aware, they are not.

Answer (score 1):

Its light rust on components that were not painted from the factory, this is normal for unpainted parts.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. but could this be a factory fault for not painting these components? or it is normal to have the knuckle and the driveshaft unpainted on most car manufacturers ? we are talking about a brand new car, so the rust has started in the factory...

Comment: I used to machine auto knuckles and other parts. It wasn't too uncommon for rust to show up before the parts left the plant. Metal rusts.

Answer (score 0):

I used to work in a steel mill that made various parts and thicknesses. a lot of the plate that parts like that get cut from are rusty and dirty from just sitting in the warehouse waiting to be cut. Most likely is the parts didn't get shipped to a powder coating factory just straight to the manufacturer.

Comment: Only issue with your thought is, these are not stamped parts. They're cast iron (knuckle) and solid rod (shaft).